# Derived subgroup of a finite non-Abelian p-group is proper?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

How do I show that the derived subgroup of a finite p-group is always proper? In Abelian groups, it's trivial. In non-Abelian groups, my intuition is that there should be some way to relate $G/Z(G)$ to $G'$, but I have no idea how.

edit: *finite*

Comment: Finite or infinite groups? If you're dealing with finite groups, recall that a finite $p$-group is nilpotent, hence solvable.

Comment: yes, sorry, finite p-groups. So then if G' = G, then [G',G'] = [G, G] = G, so it has an infinite derived series and is therefore insoluble, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A finite $p$-group $G$ has non trivial center $Z(G)$; this may be proved with the class equation. Since the center is characteristic, $G/Z(G)$ has non trivial center and we can define the ascending center series:
$$
\{1\}\subset Z(G)=Z_1(G)\subset Z_2(G)\subset\dotsb
$$
For some $n$ we must have $Z_n(G)=G$; choose $n$ minimal. Then $G'\subseteq Z_{n-1}(G)$ because, by definition, $Z_n(G)/Z_{n-1}(G)$ is abelian.